# Apache set Access-Control-Allow-Origin from http to https

Tags: wordpress, apache, bitnami

I have a basic bitnami wordpress installation. I followed their guide and setup https and automatic http to https redirection.

However when I tried to load external scripts I get the following error:

```
Failed to load https://external-script.com/: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header has a value 'http://my-site.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Origin 'https://my-site.io' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Which file should I edit and what should I add?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

You need to enable CORS in WordPress. To achieve that, you will need to set this line in the `installdir/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf` file

```
...
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/>
...
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
...
</Directory>
```

After that, you will need to restart the Apache server to load this configuration.

```
installdir/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You will also find different ways to enable CORS by following [our documentation guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/?page=apps&name=wordpress&section=how-to-enable-cors-in-wordpress).

Regards,
Jota

Comment: Yes, CORS is indeed the way to go. Good luck!